# Java Loop CSV reading

Tags: java, loops, csv

I have CSV reader that reads each line of data and prints it out to the console, the code that does this is below:

```
public void getFiles() throws IOException {

    String fileName = "CSV_FILENAME";

    try (CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
        HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy<Steps> steps =
                new HeaderColumnNameMappingStrategy<>();
        steps.setType(Steps.class);

        CsvToBean<Steps> csvToBean = new CsvToBean<>();
        List<Steps> beanList = csvToBean.parse(steps, reader);

        for (Steps step : beanList) {
            System.out.println(step);
        }

        Steps();
    }
}
```

My question is how do I get this to print out just the first row, then keep looping backround and printing each row.

So call that method, print out row 1. 
Then go back round and do the next row and so on until its read every single row.

Comment: break after  System.out.println(step);

Comment: Or you can type like `System.out.println(beanList.get(0));` You don't need any additional loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the count by doing this:

```
int count = 0;
int stop = 1;
for (Steps step : beanList) {
    if(count != stop){
        System.out.println(step);
    }
    count++;
}
```

this way you can even change the number of times it prints if you want to increase it